# MessageBird API : How can I know that the message I have sent has been read by the receiver or not?

Tags: whatsapp, messagebird

I am using **WhatsApp Business API** and in conversation, I want to know the message I have sent has been read or not by the receiver.

I have got response as 'sent', 'delivered' and other but not the 'read'.

I also have checked on my number (WhatsApp Privacy Setting) where I have set "Read receipts" enabled, if this was the case.

Could any one please help me to sort it out?

Comment: have you registered a webhook for message.updated events? that's where the 'read' notification should arrive